# How to remove duplicates from stored procedures using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, left-join, inner-join

Please check these tables.

- `FAMILY` table: FamilyID (pk), familyName
- `PARENT` table: ParentID (pk), FamilyID (fk), userName, email, password
- `KID` table: KidID (pk), FamilyID (fk), userName, email, password

Below is the stored procedure to get the parent and kid from a particular family name. Here the data is retrieved from 3 tables.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `prc_Dashboard`(IN `inputuserName` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SET @familyID = (SELECT familyID FROM PARENT WHERE userName = inputuserName); 

SELECT  
    F.familyName AS FamilyName, 
    P.userName AS Parents, 
    K.userName AS Kids 
FROM 
    PARENT P 
INNER JOIN 
    FAMILY F ON P.FamilyID = F.FamilyID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    KID K ON K.FamilyID = F.FamilyID
WHERE 
   P.FamilyID = @familyID AND F.FamilyID = @familyID
GROUP BY 
    FamilyName, Parents,Kids;
END
```

The output should be

[image]

Instead, it creates duplicates of family, parent & kids and give me 6 records.

Comment: Show us the table data as well.

Answer (score 0):

You want to combine the two lists in columns.  This is not a very "relational" thing to do.  It is possible, but not using `join`.  Instead, you can do this using aggregation:

```
select family_name, max(parent) as parent, max(kid) as kid
from ((select family_name, user_name as parent, NULL as kid
              (@rn := if(@f = family_name, @rn + 1,
                         if(@f := family_name, 1, 1)
                        )
               ) as rn
       from family f join
            parents p
            using (familyid) cross join
            (select @f := '', @rn := 0) params
       order by family_name
      ) union all
      (select family_name, NULL, k.user_name,
              (@rnk := if(@fk = family_name, @rnk + 1,
                         if(@fk := family_name, 1, 1)
                        )
               ) as rnk
       from family f join
            kids k
            using (familyid) cross join
            (select @fk := '', @rnk := 0) params
       order by family_name
      ) 
     ) pk
group by family_name, rn;
```

Comment: can you please check it again... i'm taking one parameter in the procedure which is coming from front end. And by using that i'll be getting the familyID @GordonLinoff

Comment: I'm new at this can you please simplify this for me.@GordonLinoff

Comment: @dpk . . . Run each subquery independently to see what each does.